# Raspberry low performance and low network connection

Tags: performance, raspberry-pi, cpu, raspberry-pi2

I came out my raspberry 2 B+ to make Automation after one year.

But I don't know why, my rpi is really really slow (in CPU and Network connection)

I can't watch a youtube video with raspbian for example...

I changed my os for windows 10 IOT and created a little uwp app to display webview with youtube, and it's exactly the same problem : I can watch 5s per 5s of my video in 144p (my CPU up to 100% just with one video...)

In the past I never had these problems...

Can you help me ?

I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would suggest switching to **PIXEL** (aka Raspbian).
With PIXEL, a lot of work has gone into Chromium to make it fast and (relatively) speedy, especially with YouTube.
 Finally, Chromium on the Raspberry Pi has **H.264 plug-in added** to help optimize watching videos. The Raspberry Pi's software has come a long way and improved a lot, I suggest you **give it another try** before switching to Windows 10 IOT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed PIXEL on my RPI, it's better but not perfect on YouTube. It's like video was played in 20 fps, not perfect smooth. But on other website, its ok. It's a TV Screen (28")

Comment: Glad I could help. Try switching to 480p or something lower for a higher fps. If I helped, could you select this answer as the correct one? Thanks.